# How to hide a section in .hbs and .js while taking an ember production build

Tags: node.js, ember.js, build, ember-cli, ember-pods

Our Ember application is developed in 2.8 version and we follow POD structure.

We are generating two different builds as below

1) For our dev server : No change in code,just do build

2) For our test server: Delete a section in HBS and also remove a route from router.js then do build

And we take build using "**npm run-scripts build**" which is configured in our package.json as below

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test" : "ember test"
  },
```

I would like to know in ember 2.8v can i have a condition written to remove the section based on build.

Like if i give **npm run-scripts buildDev** it will do the regular build

and  if i give **npm run-scripts buildTest** it will do sections removals and give a build

but in package.json both will be configured like

```
"scripts": {
    "build"    : "ember build",
    "buildDev" : "ember build --environment=production",
    "buildTest": "ember build --environment=production",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test" : "ember test"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to *disable* a section or do you need to *remove* it from the build?

Its pretty easy if you want to only disable something:

First you can use environment variables in your `config/environment.js`. So something like this:

```
if(process.env.DEV_BUILD) {
  ENV.disableSomething = true;
}
```

In your `package.json` you could do this:

```
"build": "cross-env DEV_BUILD=1 ember build",
```

This uses [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to set the env variable in windows and *nix systems.

You can then import the config and use it:

```
import ENV from 'hss/config/environment';

...

if(!ENV.disableSomething) {
  this.route('foo');
}

...
```

---

However if you want to actually remove some code you could write your own addon for this to replace some variable with `true` or `false`. then the minifier will remove the code.

Comment: Thanks @lux for the answer but i am not allowed to use any add-on, it should be something inbuilt or just pure javascript.

Comment: this does not use any ember addons. Also this will work without `cross-env` on `*nix` systems with `env DEV_BUILD=1 ember build`. However not on windows because the syntax to define an environment variable is different.

Comment: or are you talking about my suggestion to write an addon? Basically with "write an addon" I mean you need to write your own addon. This can be an in-repo-addon and live in the same repo. But it can use the ember addon API to do build transforms.

Comment: i meant the `cross-env` , ya i do use windows system and my ember version is 2.8.
As far as i saw in ember forums it only allows three variables by default "dev","test","production" and advised not to modify or include any more.

Comment: thats about `EMBER_ENV`. And yes, I would not change that. But you can use a custom environment variable as I suggested with `DEV_BUILD` and access this environment variable inside `config/environment` to modify futher stuff.

Comment: process.env.DEV_BUILD is not possible since DEV_BUILD is defined in package.json which triggers the ember build where the environment is mentioned as "production".
so in ember there is no scope for "DEV_BUILD"

so what happens if i will give `npm run-scripts devBuild` which will check the package.json and will trigger the ember relevant code `ember build --environment=production`  so when we do process.env.devBuild i dont think we will get any value