# EmberJs: how to dynamicaly inject data into ENV?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, npm-scripts

I need to dynamically inject some data before build stage.

In my config/environment.js i have:

```js
module.exports = function(environment) {
  environment = 'production';
  var ENV = {
    APP: {
      API_HOST: 'https://apihost1.com,
      secret: 'key1'
     }
   };
  return ENV;
};
```

How do i can to dynamically change "APP" object to something else:

```js
    APP: {
      API_HOST: 'https://apihost2.com,
      secret: 'key2'
     }
```

before build according to an executing command in my package.json?

```js
"scripts": {
    "build": "$CONFIG_NAME ember build",
},
```

I was thinking about npm scripts but could not implement that.
Is anyone has a solution for it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423370/how-to-hide-a-section-in-hbs-and-js-while-taking-an-ember-production-build/62468171#62468171) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, almost, but not 100% matches. I want to change an object in env without "if (cross-env value) " conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You need that if to differentiate different configs.

Comment: yes, and i just need to pass a config by name because i have a 30 configs. I do not want to have 30 build scripts lines in package.json and 30 if conditions in environment.js file

Comment: Ah. I see. You could do something like `require(process.env.CONFIG_NAME)`. Then you can do `env CONFIG_NAME=foo ember build `!

Comment: sorry, I do not get it. I have 30 config files: config.PLATFORM.json with { API_HOST: 'https://apihost1.com, secret: 'key1'} ....etc. How to apply your answer this this?

Comment: How do you want to decide which config to use?

Comment: If you have 30 config files that only affect the run-time configuration of your Ember application but does not affect any other part of your build, you may want to consider manually replacing run-time configuration in `index.html` after the build. This should be way more performant for such a number of scenarios as it would only require one build, copying a file 30 times and and doing some search and replace in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in `config/environment`:

```js
const customConfig = require(`./config.${process.env.CONFIG_NAME}.json`);

module.exports = function(environment) {
  environment = 'production';
  var ENV = {
    APP: {
      ...customConfig,
      otherStuff: 'bla'
     }
   };
  return ENV;
};
```

then you can run `env CONFIG_NAME=foo ember build` if you want to merge the content of the `config/config.foo.json` into the `ENV.APP` during the build.

`env` tho is a unix thing, this will work on Linux and MacOS as well as other unix systems.

For windows you can either set the env variable with PowerShell or install `cross-env` and do `npm run cross-env CONFIG_NAME=foo ember build`.